# pass information among panels in wxpython

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I have a pretty complicated wxpython app that has nested notebooks and panels. Basically the structure is that in my main frame I have a notebook (let's say notebook 1, in one page of the notebook I have two panels (upper and lower). In the lower panel I have another notebook (lets say notebook 2). So the question is how do I pass information between these two notebooks pages, and to the upper panels.

I know that there are basically three ways of passing information: by event id, by publisher, by .parent and .child. However I am really confused with the difference of these three methods and when to use them.

I have attached my code as below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import datetime, time
import wx, sys, wx.grid
import xlrd

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled

EVEN_ROW_COLOUR = '#CCE6FF'
GRID_LINE_COLOUR = '#ccc'

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class ResultTable(wx.grid.PyGridTableBase):
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        wx.grid.PyGridTableBase.__init__(self)
        self.data = data
        self.odd=wx.grid.GridCellAttr()
        self.odd.SetBackgroundColour("sky blue")
        self.odd.SetFont(wx.Font(10, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD))
        self.even=wx.grid.GridCellAttr()
        self.even.SetBackgroundColour("sea green")
        self.even.SetFont(wx.Font(10, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD))

    def GetNumberRows(self):
        return self.data.shape[0]
    def GetNumberCols(self):
        return self.data.shape[1]
    def GetValue(self, row, col):
        return self.data.loc[row][col]
    def GetColLabelValue(self, row):
        return list(self.data)[row]
    def SetValue(self, row, col, value):
        pass
    def GetAttr(self, row, col, prop):
        attr = wx.grid.GridCellAttr()
        if row % 2 == 1:
            attr.SetBackgroundColour(EVEN_ROW_COLOUR)
        return attr

class ResultTablePanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id, style=wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
        grid = wx.grid.Grid(self)


        result = pd.DataFrame({'a' : np.random.randn(100), 'b' : np.random.randn(100), 'c' : np.random.randn(100)})

        table = ResultTable(result)
        grid.SetTable(table)

        grid.AutoSize()
        grid.AutoSizeColumns(True)
        grid.SetGridLineColour(GRID_LINE_COLOUR)

        grid.EnableDragGridSize( False )

        grid.SetRowLabelSize( 50 )
        grid.SetDefaultCellAlignment( wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE )

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(grid, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

        btn_ID = parent.GetParent().GetParent().topPanel.analysisButton.GetId()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.getResult, id = btn_ID)

    def getResult(self,e):
        """
        This function should get the variables passed by the analysisOrder function,
        once the button on the SearchConditionPanel is clicked.
        """
        fileName, start_date, end_date = parent.GetParent().GetParent().topPanel.analysisOrder
        print "result get as follows:"
        print fileName, start_date, end_date



class SearchConditionPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id, style=wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)

        # Creat input box for searching time period
        nameTitleLable = wx.StaticText(self,-1, label=u"File Name:")
        self.fileNameInput = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1, "20170310221612")

        dateTitleLable = wx.StaticText(self,-1, label=u"Date range:")
        yearLable1 = wx.StaticText(self, label=u"Year:")
        monthLable1 = wx.StaticText(self,-1, label=u"Month:")
        dayLable1 = wx.StaticText(self,-1, label=u"Day:")
        yearLable2 = wx.StaticText(self,-1, label=u"Year:")
        monthLable2 = wx.StaticText(self,-1, label=u"Month:")
        dayLable2 = wx.StaticText(self,-1, label=u"Day:")
        startLable = wx.StaticText(self,-1, label=u"Start Date:")
        endLable = wx.StaticText(self,-1, label=u"End Date:")
        self.startYearInput = wx.TextCtrl(self,1, "2016")
        self.startMonthInput = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1, "10")
        self.startDayInput = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1, "30")
        self.endYearInput = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1, "2017")
        self.endMonthInput = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1, "11")
        self.endDayInput = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1, "22")

        self.analysisButton = wx.Button(self, -1, label = u'Start')
        exportButton = wx.Button(self, -1, label = u'Export')
        exportButton.Disable()

        ## Set up overall layout for the panel
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        vbox_File_button = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hbox_file = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        vbox_date = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hbox_button = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox_startDate = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox_endDate = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        hbox.Add(vbox_date, 0, wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.ALL, 5)
        hbox.Add(wx.StaticLine(self, style=wx.LI_VERTICAL), 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        hbox.Add(vbox_File_button, 0, wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.ALL, 5)

        ## Setup the layout for the right side
        vbox_File_button.Add(hbox_file, 0, wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.ALL, 5)
        vbox_File_button.Add(wx.StaticLine(self), 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        vbox_File_button.Add(hbox_button, 0, wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.ALL, 5)

        hbox_file.Add(nameTitleLable, 0, wx.TOP | wx.LEFT | wx.BOTTOM, 10)
        hbox_file.Add(self.fileNameInput, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        hbox_button.Add(self.analysisButton, 1, wx.TOP | wx.LEFT, 10)
        hbox_button.Add(exportButton, 1, wx.TOP | wx.LEFT, 10)

        ## Setup the layout for the left side
        vbox_date.Add(dateTitleLable, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        vbox_date.Add(hbox_startDate, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        vbox_date.Add(hbox_endDate, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        hbox_startDate.Add(startLable, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        hbox_startDate.Add(yearLable1, 0, wx.TOP | wx.LEFT | wx.BOTTOM, 5)
        hbox_startDate.Add(self.startYearInput, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        hbox_startDate.Add(monthLable1, 0, wx.TOP | wx.LEFT | wx.BOTTOM, 5)
        hbox_startDate.Add(self.startMonthInput, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        hbox_startDate.Add(dayLable1, 0, wx.TOP | wx.LEFT | wx.BOTTOM, 5)
        hbox_startDate.Add(self.startDayInput, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)

        hbox_endDate.Add(endLable, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, 5)
        hbox_endDate.Add(yearLable2, 0, wx.LEFT, 5)
        hbox_endDate.Add(self.endYearInput, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, 5)
        hbox_endDate.Add(monthLable2, 0, wx.LEFT, 5)
        hbox_endDate.Add(self.endMonthInput, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, 5)
        hbox_endDate.Add(dayLable2, 0, wx.LEFT, 5)
        hbox_endDate.Add(self.endDayInput, 0, wx.LEFT, 5)

        self.SetSizer(hbox)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.analysisOrder, id=self.analysisButton.GetId())


    def analysisOrder(self,e):
        fileName_temp = self.fileNameInput.GetValue().strip()
        fileName = fileName_temp + '.xls'
        start_date = self.startYearInput.GetValue().strip() + '-' + self.startMonthInput.GetValue().strip() + '-' + self.startDayInput.GetValue().strip()
        end_date = self.endYearInput.GetValue().strip() + '-' + self.endMonthInput.GetValue().strip() + '-' + self.endDayInput.GetValue().strip()

        print "analysis order button called"

        return fileName, start_date, end_date


class ResultNotebook(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        # Creat notebooks for window layout
        result_notebook = wx.Notebook(self)

        data_page = ResultTablePanel(result_notebook, -1)

        result_notebook.AddPage(data_page, u"Display Data")

        # Set up a boxsizer for the tabs
        result_notebook_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        result_notebook_sizer.Add(result_notebook, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(result_notebook_sizer)

class ModePage(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        # Localize all the panels
        self.topPanel = SearchConditionPanel(self, -1)
        self.botPanel = ResultNotebook(self)

        #Set up the panels, align and position them in the right place
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vbox.Add(self.topPanel, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        vbox.Add(self.botPanel, -1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(vbox)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)


class FreqPage(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        # t = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "This is a Frequency Page object", (20,20))

        # Localize all the panels
        topPanel = SearchConditionPanel(self, -1)
        t = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "This is a Frequency Page object")

        #Set up the panels, align and position them in the right place
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vbox.Add(topPanel, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        vbox.Add(t, -1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(vbox)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

class OrderPage(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        # Localize all the panels
        self.topPanel = SearchConditionPanel(self, -1)
        self.botPanel = ResultNotebook(self)

        #Set up the panels, align and position them in the right place
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vbox.Add(self.topPanel, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        vbox.Add(self.botPanel, -1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(vbox)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)


class ShopPage(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        # Creat notebooks for window layout
        shop_notebook = wx.Notebook(self)

        mode_page = ModePage(shop_notebook)
        freq_page = FreqPage(shop_notebook)

        shop_notebook.AddPage(mode_page, u"Mode Analysis")
        shop_notebook.AddPage(freq_page, u"Frequency Analysis")

        # Set up a boxsizer for the tabs
        shop_page_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        shop_page_sizer.Add(shop_notebook, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(shop_page_sizer)



##**----------------------------------------------------------------------------------**##
##**-------------- Create a windows to display the entire system ---------------------**##    
class OrderAnalysis(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(1024, 576))
        # self.Maximize(True)  # Default display to be maximized

        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        # Creat notebooks for window layout
        main_notebook = wx.Notebook(panel, style=wx.NB_LEFT)

        main_notebook.SetFont(wx.Font(10, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT,
                         wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL, 
                         wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL))

        # create the page windows as children of the notebook
        order_page = OrderPage(main_notebook)
        shop_page = ShopPage(main_notebook)

        # add the pages to the notebook with the label to show on the tab
        main_notebook.AddPage(order_page, u"Order Analysis")
        main_notebook.AddPage(shop_page, u"Shop Analysis")


        # finally, put the notebook in a sizer for the panel to manage
        # the layout
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(main_notebook, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)


        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    OrderAnalysis(None, -1, 'Order Info Analyser')
    app.MainLoop()
```

As you can see, I have a search condition panel and a result panel that are used in different pages. For each specific page, the search condition and result could be different and only for that page. So my question is, what is the best way to pass the search condition (i.e. data and file name) to the corresponding page to display the result (i.e. the "getResult" function inside "ResultTablePanel" doesn't work).

For example, inside the "order page", the search condition panel has user input  start and end dates, and the file name. Below the search condition panel is the result panel showing the computed result based on the search condition. Once the "Start" button is clicked, the "start date", "end date" and "file name" variables are passed to the result panel ("ResultTablePanel") within the "order page". Similarly, since the "Mode page" also calls both "ResultTablePanel" and "SearchConditionPanel", it should have its own "start date", "end date" and "file name" variables (note that they can be same or different from the ones inside "order page"), and its own result displayed in "ResultTablePanel".

Thank you in advance for taking time reviewing and answering my question.

================================================================================

Thank you guys for the help, I have figured it out using PubSub and .parent methods combined. I have attached my solution code as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import datetime, time
import wx, sys, wx.grid
import xlrd

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled

EVEN_ROW_COLOUR = '#CCE6FF'
GRID_LINE_COLOUR = '#ccc'

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from wx.lib.pubsub import pub 

class ResultTable(wx.grid.PyGridTableBase):
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        wx.grid.PyGridTableBase.__init__(self)
        self.data = data
        self.odd=wx.grid.GridCellAttr()
        self.odd.SetBackgroundColour("sky blue")
        self.odd.SetFont(wx.Font(10, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD))
        self.even=wx.grid.GridCellAttr()
        self.even.SetBackgroundColour("sea green")
        self.even.SetFont(wx.Font(10, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD))

    def GetNumberRows(self):
        if self.data.empty:
            return 5
        else:
            return self.data.shape[0]
    def GetNumberCols(self):
        if self.data.empty:
            return 5
        else:
            return self.data.shape[1]
    def GetValue(self, row, col):
        if self.data.empty:
            return None
        else:
            return self.data.loc[row][col]
    def GetColLabelValue(self, row):
        if self.data.empty:
            return None
        else:
            return list(self.data)[row]
    def SetValue(self, row, col, value):
        pass
    def GetAttr(self, row, col, prop):
        attr = wx.grid.GridCellAttr()
        if row % 2 == 1:
            attr.SetBackgroundColour(EVEN_ROW_COLOUR)
        return attr

    def ResetView(self):
        """Trim/extend the control's rows and update all values"""
        self.getGrid().BeginBatch()
        for current, new, delmsg, addmsg in [
                (self.currentRows, self.GetNumberRows(), wx.grid.GRIDTABLE_NOTIFY_ROWS_DELETED, wx.grid.GRIDTABLE_NOTIFY_ROWS_APPENDED),
                (self.currentColumns, self.GetNumberCols(), wx.grid.GRIDTABLE_NOTIFY_COLS_DELETED, wx.grid.GRIDTABLE_NOTIFY_COLS_APPENDED),
        ]:
                if new < current:
                        msg = wx.grid.GridTableMessage(
                                self,
                                delmsg,
                                new,    # position
                                current-new,
                        )
                        self.getGrid().ProcessTableMessage(msg)
                elif new > current:
                        msg = wx.grid.GridTableMessage(
                                self,
                                addmsg,
                                new-current
                        )
                        self.getGrid().ProcessTableMessage(msg)
        self.UpdateValues()
        self.getGrid().EndBatch()

        # The scroll bars aren't resized (at least on windows)
        # Jiggling the size of the window rescales the scrollbars
        h,w = grid.GetSize()
        grid.SetSize((h+1, w))
        grid.SetSize((h, w))
        grid.ForceRefresh()

    def UpdateValues( self ):
        """Update all displayed values"""
        msg = wx.grid.GridTableMessage(self, wx.grid.GRIDTABLE_REQUEST_VIEW_GET_VALUES)
        self.getGrid().ProcessTableMessage(msg)

class ResultTablePanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, page):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id, style=wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
        self.grid = wx.grid.Grid(self)

        self.parent = parent

        result = pd.DataFrame({'0' : np.random.randn(100), 'b' : np.random.randn(100), 'c' : np.random.randn(100)})
        result = pd.DataFrame()

        table = ResultTable(result)
        self.grid.SetTable(table)

        self.grid.AutoSize()
        self.grid.AutoSizeColumns(True)
        self.grid.SetGridLineColour(GRID_LINE_COLOUR)

        self.grid.EnableDragGridSize( False )

        self.grid.SetRowLabelSize( 50 )
        self.grid.SetDefaultCellAlignment( wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE )

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.grid, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

        pub.subscribe(self.getResult, "panelListener")

    def getResult(self, message, page):
        """
        This function should get the variables passed by the analysisOrder function,
        once the button on the SearchConditionPanel is clicked.
        """
        result = pd.DataFrame()

        if page == "Order" and self.parent.GetParent().GetParent().page_identifier == "Order":
            # For test purpose only
            result = pd.DataFrame({'0' : np.random.randn(100), 'b' : np.random.randn(100), 'c' : np.random.randn(100)})  ## For test only

            print "Update Order page"
            table = ResultTable(result)
            self.grid.SetTable(table)
            self.Refresh()
        if page == "Mode" and self.parent.GetParent().GetParent().page_identifier == "Mode":
            result = pd.DataFrame({'0' : np.random.randn(1000), 'b' : np.random.randn(1000)})  ## For test only
            print "Update Mode page"
            table = ResultTable(result)
            self.grid.SetTable(table)
            self.Refresh()
        else:
            pass


class SearchConditionPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, pageID):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id, style=wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)

        # Creat input box for searching time period
        nameTitleLable = wx.StaticText(self,-1, label=u"File Name:")
        self.fileNameInput = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1, "20170310221612")

        dateTitleLable = wx.StaticText(self,-1, label=u"Date range:")
        yearLable1 = wx.StaticText(self, label=u"Year:")
        monthLable1 = wx.StaticText(self,-1, label=u"Month:")
        dayLable1 = wx.StaticText(self,-1, label=u"Day:")
        yearLable2 = wx.StaticText(self,-1, label=u"Year:")
        monthLable2 = wx.StaticText(self,-1, label=u"Month:")
        dayLable2 = wx.StaticText(self,-1, label=u"Day:")
        startLable = wx.StaticText(self,-1, label=u"Start Date:")
        endLable = wx.StaticText(self,-1, label=u"End Date:")
        self.startYearInput = wx.TextCtrl(self,1, "2016")
        self.startMonthInput = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1, "10")
        self.startDayInput = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1, "30")
        self.endYearInput = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1, "2017")
        self.endMonthInput = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1, "11")
        self.endDayInput = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1, "22")

        self.analysisButton = wx.Button(self, -1, label = u'Start')
        exportButton = wx.Button(self, -1, label = u'Export')
        exportButton.Disable()

        ## Set up overall layout for the panel
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        vbox_File_button = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hbox_file = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        vbox_date = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hbox_button = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox_startDate = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox_endDate = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        hbox.Add(vbox_date, 0, wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.ALL, 5)
        hbox.Add(wx.StaticLine(self, style=wx.LI_VERTICAL), 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        hbox.Add(vbox_File_button, 0, wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.ALL, 5)

        ## Setup the layout for the right side
        vbox_File_button.Add(hbox_file, 0, wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.ALL, 5)
        vbox_File_button.Add(wx.StaticLine(self), 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        vbox_File_button.Add(hbox_button, 0, wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.ALL, 5)

        hbox_file.Add(nameTitleLable, 0, wx.TOP | wx.LEFT | wx.BOTTOM, 10)
        hbox_file.Add(self.fileNameInput, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        hbox_button.Add(self.analysisButton, 1, wx.TOP | wx.LEFT, 10)
        hbox_button.Add(exportButton, 1, wx.TOP | wx.LEFT, 10)

        ## Setup the layout for the left side
        vbox_date.Add(dateTitleLable, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        vbox_date.Add(hbox_startDate, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        vbox_date.Add(hbox_endDate, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        hbox_startDate.Add(startLable, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        hbox_startDate.Add(yearLable1, 0, wx.TOP | wx.LEFT | wx.BOTTOM, 5)
        hbox_startDate.Add(self.startYearInput, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        hbox_startDate.Add(monthLable1, 0, wx.TOP | wx.LEFT | wx.BOTTOM, 5)
        hbox_startDate.Add(self.startMonthInput, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        hbox_startDate.Add(dayLable1, 0, wx.TOP | wx.LEFT | wx.BOTTOM, 5)
        hbox_startDate.Add(self.startDayInput, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)

        hbox_endDate.Add(endLable, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, 5)
        hbox_endDate.Add(yearLable2, 0, wx.LEFT, 5)
        hbox_endDate.Add(self.endYearInput, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, 5)
        hbox_endDate.Add(monthLable2, 0, wx.LEFT, 5)
        hbox_endDate.Add(self.endMonthInput, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, 5)
        hbox_endDate.Add(dayLable2, 0, wx.LEFT, 5)
        hbox_endDate.Add(self.endDayInput, 0, wx.LEFT, 5)

        self.SetSizer(hbox)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.analysisOrder, id=self.analysisButton.GetId())
        self.page_ID = pageID

    def analysisOrder(self,e):
        fileName_temp = self.fileNameInput.GetValue().strip()
        fileName = fileName_temp + '.xls'
        start_date = self.startYearInput.GetValue().strip() + '-' + self.startMonthInput.GetValue().strip() + '-' + self.startDayInput.GetValue().strip()
        end_date = self.endYearInput.GetValue().strip() + '-' + self.endMonthInput.GetValue().strip() + '-' + self.endDayInput.GetValue().strip()

        print "analysis order button called"
        pub.sendMessage("panelListener", message=fileName, page = self.page_ID)

        return fileName, start_date, end_date


class ResultNotebook(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, pageID):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        # Creat notebooks for window layout
        result_notebook = wx.Notebook(self)

        self.data_page = ResultTablePanel(result_notebook, -1, page = pageID)

        result_notebook.AddPage(self.data_page, u"Display Data")

        # Set up a boxsizer for the tabs
        result_notebook_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        result_notebook_sizer.Add(result_notebook, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(result_notebook_sizer)

class ModePage(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.page_identifier = "Mode"

        # Localize all the panels
        self.topPanel = SearchConditionPanel(self, -1, pageID = "Mode")
        self.botPanel = ResultNotebook(self, pageID = "Mode")

        #Set up the panels, align and position them in the right place
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vbox.Add(self.topPanel, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        vbox.Add(self.botPanel, -1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(vbox)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)


class FreqPage(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        # t = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "This is a Frequency Page object", (20,20))

        # Localize all the panels
        topPanel = SearchConditionPanel(self, -1, pageID = "Frequency")
        t = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "This is a Frequency Page object")

        #Set up the panels, align and position them in the right place
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vbox.Add(topPanel, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        vbox.Add(t, -1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(vbox)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

class OrderPage(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.page_identifier = "Order"

        # Localize all the panels
        self.topPanel = SearchConditionPanel(self, -1, pageID = "Order")
        self.botPanel = ResultNotebook(self, pageID = "Order")

        #Set up the panels, align and position them in the right place
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vbox.Add(self.topPanel, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        vbox.Add(self.botPanel, -1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(vbox)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)


class ShopPage(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        # Creat notebooks for window layout
        shop_notebook = wx.Notebook(self)

        mode_page = ModePage(shop_notebook)
        freq_page = FreqPage(shop_notebook)

        shop_notebook.AddPage(mode_page, u"Mode Analysis")
        shop_notebook.AddPage(freq_page, u"Frequency Analysis")

        # Set up a boxsizer for the tabs
        shop_page_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        shop_page_sizer.Add(shop_notebook, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(shop_page_sizer)

##**----------------------------------------------------------------------------------**##
##**-------------- Create a windows to display the entire system ---------------------**##    
class OrderAnalysis(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(1024, 576))
        # self.Maximize(True)  # Default display to be maximized

        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        # Creat notebooks for window layout
        main_notebook = wx.Notebook(panel, style=wx.NB_LEFT)

        main_notebook.SetFont(wx.Font(10, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT,
                         wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL, 
                         wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL))

        # create the page windows as children of the notebook
        order_page = OrderPage(main_notebook)
        shop_page = ShopPage(main_notebook)

        # add the pages to the notebook with the label to show on the tab
        main_notebook.AddPage(order_page, u"Order Analysis")
        main_notebook.AddPage(shop_page, u"Shop Analysis")


        # finally, put the notebook in a sizer for the panel to manage
        # the layout
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(main_notebook, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)


        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    OrderAnalysis(None, -1, 'Order Info Analyser')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Thank you everyone again! Much appreciated.

Comment: Edit your code down to relevant portions so you don't risk crushing innocent bystanders.

Comment: also i dont understand what you are asking for .... try and explain better? ie theres 50 things in the searchcondition panel ... what do you do with the other inputs?  .... (as an aside there is a wx.DatePickerCtrl I think)

Comment: Hi, I have Modified my code (functions "ResultTablePanel" and "analysisOrder"), and my last paragraph, hopefully this will make my question more clear. As I have "ResultTablePanel" and "SearchConditionPanel" imported by different pages of different notebooks, my question is how do I pass variables from "SearchConditionPanel" to "ResultTablePanel" within any specific page of a notebook. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually recommend using Pubsub for this sort of thing. It's very easy to implement and makes it easy to pass a message to one or more recipients (panels).

Here's a simple example:

```
import wx
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub 


class OtherFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Secondary Frame")
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        msg = "Enter a Message to send to the main frame"
        instructions = wx.StaticText(panel, label=msg)
        self.msgTxt = wx.TextCtrl(panel, value="")
        closeBtn = wx.Button(panel, label="Send and Close")
        closeBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onSendAndClose)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        flags = wx.ALL|wx.CENTER
        sizer.Add(instructions, 0, flags, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.msgTxt, 0, flags, 5)
        sizer.Add(closeBtn, 0, flags, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    def onSendAndClose(self, event):
        """
        Send a message and close frame
        """
        msg = self.msgTxt.GetValue()
        pub.sendMessage("panelListener", message=msg)
        pub.sendMessage("panelListener", message="test2", arg2="2nd argument!")
        self.Close()


class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        pub.subscribe(self.myListener, "panelListener")

        btn = wx.Button(self, label="Open Frame")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onOpenFrame)

    def myListener(self, message, arg2=None):
        """
        Listener function
        """
        print "Received the following message: " + message
        if arg2:
            print "Received another arguments: " + str(arg2)

    def onOpenFrame(self, event):
        """
        Opens secondary frame
        """
        frame = OtherFrame()
        frame.Show()


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="PubSub Tutorial")
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

And here is some additional information:

- https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.pubsub.html
- https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/09/05/wxpython-2-9-and-the-newer-pubsub-api-a-simple-tutorial/

Comment: Mike probably knows the most about wxPython out of anyone in the world (including Robin Dunn :P (although im sure Robin knows more about the implementation details :P) I would listen to his words of wisdom

Comment: Haha! Robin knows way more than I do. He has an encyclopedic memory and can answer just about any question I've asked him on the spot.

Comment: Hi Mike, it works like magic, except that there is one problem that I'm trying to figure out: if I have a panel that is called by different pages inside a notebook, how do I have the panel display different things for different pages? Or should I create panels for each page? For example, in my example, "ResultTablePanel" and "SearchConditionPanel" are two panels that are called by all the pages of the notebook, but each page has its own conditions passed from "SearchConditionPanel" to "ResultTablePanel". I do not know how to make this work. Thanks.

Comment: Why not modify your SearchConditionPanel to take an additional parameter, the associated ResultTablePanel.  Then in the event handler you can just call functions in the ResultTablePanel directly.

Comment: You can pass entire objects around with pubsub or just pass some kind of parameter along that tells your code to show different pages or whatever.

Comment: @PaulCornelius because I'm stupid, thanks for the heads up, got it working now

Comment: @MikeDriscoll Thank you so much, got it working finally:)

Answer (score 2):

You mention three ways of passing information but I have to confess I don't understand what you are talking about (and I've written many wxWidget applications).  One way of handling the situation you describe is for the event handler to call a function in the parent class, which can then relay the information to other functions/classes.  Schematically:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        B(self)
        self.c = C(self)

    def a_function(self, *data):
        # do something with the data 
        # you can pass the information to class C here

class B:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    def an_event_handler(self):
        data = something
        self.parent.a_function(data)
        # or use wx.CallAfter for later execution

class C:
    pass
```

Another solution is the MVC concept, where your event handler passes its information to a model class which stores it or processes it further.  This model class can raise a custom wx Event, which components of the UI can then handle as necessary to redraw any affected widgets.

Comment: ive also written many many wx programs and dont understand what the question is :P

Comment: also might be worth mentioning wx.lib.pubsub (although custom events **mostly** cover this) +1

Comment: Hi, I have Modified my code (functions "ResultTablePanel" and "analysisOrder"), and my last paragraph, hopefully this will make my question more clear. As I have "ResultTablePanel" and "SearchConditionPanel" imported by different pages of different notebooks, my question is how do I pass variables from "SearchConditionPanel" to "ResultTablePanel" within any specific page of a notebook.

For the 3 ways I mentioned, one way is to calls its parent class. Another way is to check event_ID using event.GetId(). The third way I was talking about was wx.lib.pubsub. I am confused how to use them.